# How do I cancel the tracking of two or more functions on the buttons at once?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one such problem with my website. I have chapters on the page and in each, there are some modules and theories. In theory, I have the function of reading more so that the text is not just exposed. But the problem arises in that when I have a theory with this function on page 2 or more, the first one works for me and the others do not work as they should and track the first one, and it happens that only the first one works. How do I fix or rewrite it?

My code to read more in js:

```
function readMore(){
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more")
    var btnText = document.getElementById("btn")

    if(dots.style.display == "none"){
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Číst dále"
        moreText.style.display = "none";
    }else{
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Zavřít"
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Piece of my HTML code for theories:

```
<div class="theory">
        <h3>Rastrová grafika</h3>
        <p>Rastrová grafika (či bitmapová grafika) je jeden ze dvou základních způsobů, jakým počítače ukládají a zpracovávají obrazové informace (druhý způsob je vektorová grafika).
            V rastrové grafice je celý obrázek <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">popsán pomocí jednotlivých barevných bodů (pixelů). Body jsou uspořádány do mřížky. 
            Každý bod má určen svou přesnou polohu a barvu v nějakém barevném modelu (např. RGB). Tento způsob popisu obrázků používá např. televize nebo digitální fotoaparát.</span></p>
            <button onclick="readMore()" id="btn" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="theory">
        <h3>Souřadnice</h3>
        <p>Soustava souřadnic (též souřadnicová soustava či systém souřadnic) umožňuje jednoznačně popsat polohu bodu pomocí čísel jakožto souřadnic čili koordinát. Geometrické úlohy je pak možno řešit <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">matematickými prostředky, což je základ analytické geometrie. 
            Polohu bodu na přímce určuje jedno (reálné) číslo, v rovině dvě, v prostoru tři čísla atd. Obecně je k určení polohy bodu v n-rozměrném prostoru třeba n čísel, která tvoří uspořádané n-tice (čti entice), neboť na jejich pořadí záleží. 
            Polohu přímky lze pak označit pomocí dvou bodů, polohu roviny pomocí tří bodů a podobně i pro další geometrické útvary.</span></p>
            <button onclick="readMore()" id="btn" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
    </div>
```

The problem is mainly on the codes page. I'm sorry it's Czech and not English, but I still hope you can advise me. The link to my page is below.

My website - http://litecode.net/

Comment: id must be unique, use class for buttons.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @JakubMitrega, `id="btn"`

Comment: It doesn't work anyway @s.kuznetsov

Comment: @JakubMitrega, This is not a solution. This is just a remark.

Comment: I know no but sinisake wrote me above that I should use the class on the buttons but it doesn't work, @s.kuznetsov

Comment: @Jakub Mitrega, yes, but you have to change code accordingly...I will check it, asap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i have added classes where you have used id's, because id's can't be duplicated, and i have added one small change to your function call, adding current button element as argument.

So, your HTML should look like this now:

```
<div class="theory">
    <h3>Rastrová grafika</h3>
    <p>Rastrová grafika (či bitmapová grafika) je jeden ze dvou základních způsobů, jakým počítače ukládají a zpracovávají obrazové informace (druhý způsob je vektorová grafika).
        V rastrové grafice je celý obrázek <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">popsán pomocí jednotlivých barevných bodů (pixelů). Body jsou uspořádány do mřížky. 
        Každý bod má určen svou přesnou polohu a barvu v nějakém barevném modelu (např. RGB). Tento způsob popisu obrázků používá např. televize nebo digitální fotoaparát.</span></p>
        <button onclick="readMore(this)" class="btn" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="theory">
    <h3>Souřadnice</h3>
    <p>Soustava souřadnic (též souřadnicová soustava či systém souřadnic) umožňuje jednoznačně popsat polohu bodu pomocí čísel jakožto souřadnic čili koordinát. Geometrické úlohy je pak možno řešit <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">matematickými prostředky, což je základ analytické geometrie. 
        Polohu bodu na přímce určuje jedno (reálné) číslo, v rovině dvě, v prostoru tři čísla atd. Obecně je k určení polohy bodu v n-rozměrném prostoru třeba n čísel, která tvoří uspořádané n-tice (čti entice), neboť na jejich pořadí záleží. 
        Polohu přímky lze pak označit pomocí dvou bodů, polohu roviny pomocí tří bodů a podobně i pro další geometrické útvary.</span></p>
        <button onclick="readMore(this)" class"btn" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
</div>
```

Then, small change in CSS:

```
.more{
    display: none;
}
```

And, finally, updated javascript, with the same (good) logic, but with targeting of the right elements:

```
function readMore(el) {
    dots = el.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1];
    more = el.previousElementSibling.childNodes[2];
    if (dots.style.display == "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        el.innerHTML = "Číst dále"
        more.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        el.innerHTML = "Zavřít"
        more.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

DEMO:

```js
function readMore(el) {
    dots = el.previousElementSibling.childNodes[1];
    more = el.previousElementSibling.childNodes[2];
    if (dots.style.display == "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        el.innerHTML = "Číst dále"
        more.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        el.innerHTML = "Zavřít"
        more.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```css
body.dark .theory {
    /*letter-spacing: -1px;*/
    color: white;
}

body .theory {
    /*letter-spacing: -1px;*/
    /*word-spacing: -2px;*/
    color: black;
}

.theory-btn{
    
}

.more{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="theory">
        <h3>Rastrová grafika</h3>
        <p>Rastrová grafika (či bitmapová grafika) je jeden ze dvou základních způsobů, jakým počítače ukládají a zpracovávají obrazové informace (druhý způsob je vektorová grafika).
            V rastrové grafice je celý obrázek <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">popsán pomocí jednotlivých barevných bodů (pixelů). Body jsou uspořádány do mřížky. 
            Každý bod má určen svou přesnou polohu a barvu v nějakém barevném modelu (např. RGB). Tento způsob popisu obrázků používá např. televize nebo digitální fotoaparát.</span></p>
            <button onclick="readMore(this)" class="btn" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="theory">
        <h3>Souřadnice</h3>
        <p>Soustava souřadnic (též souřadnicová soustava či systém souřadnic) umožňuje jednoznačně popsat polohu bodu pomocí čísel jakožto souřadnic čili koordinát. Geometrické úlohy je pak možno řešit <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">matematickými prostředky, což je základ analytické geometrie. 
            Polohu bodu na přímce určuje jedno (reálné) číslo, v rovině dvě, v prostoru tři čísla atd. Obecně je k určení polohy bodu v n-rozměrném prostoru třeba n čísel, která tvoří uspořádané n-tice (čti entice), neboť na jejich pořadí záleží. 
            Polohu přímky lze pak označit pomocí dvou bodů, polohu roviny pomocí tří bodů a podobně i pro další geometrické útvary.</span></p>
            <button onclick="readMore(this)" class"btn" class="theory-btn">Číst dále</button>
    </div>
```